# How exactly does $PATH work in Terminal on Macs and how exactly does .zshrc file influence it?

Tags: macos, terminal, path, zsh

I'm new to programming, to Macs and I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how Terminal works in relation to `$PATH` and the .zshrc file.

To preface this somewhat: I'm working on a Macbook Pro 14 running the M1 Pro, and am trying my hand at programming.
I've been going through the Flutter installation and setup process and at some point, the tutorial I'm following has told me to declare the path of my Flutter SDK by adding that path to my .zshrc file. And so I did, as so:

`export PATH=$HOME/dev/tooling/flutter/bin:$PATH`

I saved the file and restarted Terminal and tried calling `flutter doctor` and it works - fantastic, my arms are happy-flailing in the air. Commenting out the path added means I can't call it in Terminal anymore by just typing `flutter` when I'm working outside of the `.../flutter/bin` directory - makes sense to me.

Somewhere a little further down the tutorial, I'm instructed to install Java, so I do. I install Azul's Zulu Java for Macs running on ARM architecture and again, I'm told to declare the path to Java in my .zshrc file as so:

`export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-18.jdk/Contents/Home`

I do it I call `java` and try calling `java -version` and they both work.

**Now, the problem begins from the next step**

In the next step I am told to install Android Studio, which I do. I then go back to Terminal and run `flutter doctor` and it highlights Android toolchain as an issue, expanding to say that `cmdline-tools component is missing`. I do a search and find a suggested solution about ticking *Android SDK Command-line Tools* in *Android Studio > System Settings > Android SDK > SDK Tools*, followed by declaring two folders named *tools* and *platform-tools*.
I do as instructed but ultimately, I end up declaring it with the wrong syntax and on top of that, realised that I didn't click *apply* when I ticked the *Android SDK Command-line Tools* in Android Studio. So then my .zshrc file looked like this:

```
export PATH=$HOME/dev/tooling/flutter/bin:$PATH

export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-18.jdk/Contents/Home

export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

Immediately after I saved the .zshrc file and restarted Terminal, none of the commands were recognised. Not `flutter` nor `flutter doctor` nor `java` or `java -version`; or even `vim ~/.zshrc`.
I scratch my head, reopen the .zshrc file and comment out the last two newly added lines, restart Terminal and voila, it's all okay again.

To add to the confusion, I then edit my .zshrc file to look like this (the second line of code was intentionally written in what I now knew was incorrect syntax to see what affects it'd have):

```
export PATH=$HOME/dev/tooling/flutter/bin:$PATH

export PATH=$HOME$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools
#export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-18.jdk/Contents/Home

#export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools
#export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

and calling `flutter` and `flutter doctor` doesn't work; however calling `java` and `java -version` does (which leads me to believe that my line declaring a path for java is pretty pointless). But then when I re-edited my .zshrc file to look like this:

```
export PATH=$HOME/dev/tooling/flutter/bin:$PATH

#export PATH=$HOME$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools
#export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/zulu-18.jdk/Contents/Home

export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools
```

none of the commands work - not `flutter` nor `flutter doctor` or `java` etc.

What's the deal here? I'm pretty confused. I'm guessing it has something to do with the positioning of `$PATH` in the active lines of code but I can't quite figure it out.

It's a long read and likely a very silly question but it will eat at me if I can't get to the bottom of it lol. Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean by _don't work_? Do you get any error message? BTW, if you really set up the PATH in .zshrc, every interactive subshell will get the same directories prepended over and over again. You can avoid this by putting a `typeset -aU path` into your `.zshrc` (exactly this spelling). Also, I would consider putting it into your `.zshenv` instead of `.zshrc`, to ensure that the settings are also done for non-interactive shells.

Comment: Hey, appreciate the answer. By *don't work*, I mean Terminal returns ```command not found```. Also, what exactly does it mean if the same directories are prepended over and over again? And what are the implications and why does it happen? Sorry for all the noncy questions, I just really want to understand the working of it all

Comment: Sure you get this error, when you destroy your PATH....  ;-D  If the answer solves your problem, I would be glad if you could accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a

```
export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools
```

you destroy the old setting (i.e. $HOME/dev/tooling/flutter/bin:$PATH). I would write instead

```
path+=(~/Library/Android/sdk/tools)
```

which would append the new directory to the existing PATH.

Comment: Ahh right, thank you again. May I ask why it is that 
```export PATH=$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools``` destroys the old setting and also returns ```command not found``` when calling ```java``` 

but


```export PATH=$HOME$PATH:$HOME/Library/Android/sdk/tools``` allows me to still call ```java``` in Terminal but not ```flutter```. What is/are the difference(s) that matter in those two declared paths?
Cheers!

Comment: In the first case, you set PATH to a completely new value. In the second case, the right-hand side of the assignment still contains `$PATH` burried in it (though in not a very meaningful way). You can observe the effect if you run your code with `set -x`.  It's a bit like in nearly every programming language when you do a `x=25` (set the value hard) compared to a `x = x+25` (where the old value is reused to calculate the new one).

Comment: Ahh, I gotchyu now! I think that leaves me with one final question:
I've read elsewhere that Terminal accesses multiple files for paths when a command is executed, one of them being the .zshrc file. What is the priority of the .zshrc file vs the other files that MacOS innately creates upon installation?
Cheers!

Comment: This is not related to MacOS, but to zsh. Do a `man zshall` and search for a chapter titled _STARTUP/SHUTDOWN FILES_. This shows what files zsh is processing under what conditions. AFIK, the only point in that MacOS comes into play, is that it already installs severa files in `/etc`, some of them being relevant for zsh as well, and you are not supposed to touch them.

Comment: Thank you so much. I wasn't far from pulling my hair out over understanding this lol. Much appreciated!